# Wrap text around block element

Tags: html, css

Here example code

```
<div id="field_one">
    <p>   ndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange</p>

<div id="field_two">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Css

```
div#field_one {
    width:400px; 
    height: 200px; 
    float: left;
}
div#field_two{ 
    float:right; 
    width:200px; 
    height: 100px;
    background: green
}
```

I need you to wrap text around a block element and was with him at the same level;
Here is link on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h58Ra/14/) what i am trying to achive, but text should wrap that div element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply put a `margin` on a floated element to reposition it; this will not make it work as you intend it.

Instead, change the order of the elements:
http://jsfiddle.net/h58Ra/26/

Edit:

If you cannot change the order of the elements in the HTML code, consider changing the order of the elements with jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/h58Ra/30/

The jQuery I did here saves the floated element in a variable, removes it from its old position and then prepends it in the parent div.

```
var field_two = $("#field_two");
field_two.remove();
$("#field_one").prepend(field_two);
```

​

Comment: i know it just a simple example, and this block should be at the bottom of the first div

Comment: For what reason does it have to be on the bottom?

Comment: ok, in my project that *div#field_two* appends on few different pages, and always should be at the bottom of *field_one* :/

Comment: Are you the one adding the div? If you were for example adding it with jQuery, you could simply prepend it instead of appending it. Or is it a CMS that is generating the code?

Comment: yep CMS Drupal, *second div* is generated, but i can manipulate it with jQuery too

Comment: great, with some jQuery manipulation i made it :>, used *last* selector

Answer (score 0):

simple answer - put your div#field2 before the P (and get rid of the negative top margin)

e.g.

```
<div id="field_one">
  <div id="field_two">
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>one</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p>   ndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchange</p>
</div>
```

It's not nice from a semantic point of view, but it's the easiest way to make it work.

Edit: while I think of it, the CSS in the jsfiddle was a bit broken too (missing a semi-colon separator between the height value and the second float (which isn't required)